# Настройка golang после установки (win 10).

Tags: golang

Всё делал по инструкциям https://golang.org/doc/install

Проблема.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Printf("hello, world\n")
}
```

Данный код после команды go build успешно компилируется, но при запуске исполняемого файла cmd быстро открывается и сразу закрывается. А если запустить через командную строку win говорит это:

> hello : Имя "hello" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария или выполняемой программы. Проверьте правильность написания
>   имени, а также наличие и правильность пути, после чего повторите попытку.
>   строка:1 знак:1
>   + hello+ ~~~~~    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (hello:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Но странно следующее, go run hello.go успешно компилирует и исполняет.

Comment: Подозреваю, что у вас чего-то не хватает в PATH. Что касается того, что cmd закрывается, так это нормально. Отработав, он закрывает окно.

Comment: А `.\hello.exe`?